# How to get the parent of a JSON element?

Tags: python

How can I get the parent of the element in JSON? For example, In the JSON below,

When I use `print(json["phones"])`, the result I want to happpen is:

```
[iphone1, iphone2]
```

but instead, I am getting this:

```
{'iphone1': {'test': ''}, 'iphone2': {'test': ''}}
```

Sorry I am new on python and JSON, the sample code is below. Thank you!

```
{
  "phones":
  {
    "iphone1":
    {
      "test": ""
    },

    "iphone2":
    {
      "test": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You definitely want to convert your json into a dictionary as a dict will let you manipulate things better. Also, once it's a dictionary you will gain access to the `.keys()` function that will do exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I print(json["phones"]), the result I want to happpen is:
>
> ```
> [iphone1, iphone2]
> ```

What do you mean by `iphone1`? You mean `"iphone1"`?

---

What you want are the `key`s of the JSON `object` (equivalent to Python `dict`), so you can use the `dict().keys()` method, which returns a `list` with the keys of the dictionary.

```
>>> print(json["phones"])
{'iphone1': {'test': ''}, 'iphone2': {'test': ''}}
>>> print(json["phones"].keys())
['iphone1', 'iphone2']
```

Comment: I see I'm getting a couple of upvotes, thank you for this +10s. If among the upvoters there was the OP @Ppap please let me know that, if the solution didn't work feel free to ask, otherwise accept the answer.